A-Frame and AR.js not loading gltf
I have the code below which I am expecting would render the gltf I have locally in the same folder but it is not rendering. Based on the network traffic, I can see the textures/meshes coming through ok with 200, but nothing rendering.
<html>
<head>
    <!-- include A-Frame obviously -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <!-- create your content here. just a gltf for now -->
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="car" src="scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
    

      <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
      <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'>
        <a-entity
            animation-mixer
            gltf-model="#car"
            scale="0.2 0.2 0.2"
            position='0 1 -3'>
        </a-entity>
      </a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>```

I am working from the tutorial on this page: https://aframe.io/blog/arjs/
The image tracker example using the hiro preset with a simple preset works but I have not been able to load anything else than a box or other built-in geometries as a scene object.

